# SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (Release 16) keeps on crashing

Tags: ssms, memory, sql-server-2016

After updating to Release 16, my SSMS keeps on disconnecting automatically and brings up the Connect to Database Engine pop-up (screenshot below). Additionally, I keep on getting the "**System.OutOfMemoryException**" when I run queries, even though my machine has 16GB RAM and is only currently using about 4GB. These errors happen with simple queries like `SELECT GETDATE();` Any suggestions on what could be the issue? [image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not alone. See more details [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3074856).

Posted by Microsoft:

> Turns out there's a thread leak in a utility class. The number of
>   threads leaked will be proportional to the number of registered
>   servers you have, among other things. A fix is coming in the next
>   release

Answer (score 4):

Removing servers from **Registered Servers** will stop SSMS from crashing. If you can afford to do so, I'd recommend it till Microsoft releases a fix.